# Boostrap image slider not working when publishing site online

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap image slider in my project, I only need the bootstrap js and css file for that slider. Everything works fine till I publish my site online. Then the imageslider is nowhere, the images aren't shown, just a white space.
I included jquery and popper because I read that is necessary but still it does not work. Why is that?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="./scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="./styles/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./styles/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./styles/allstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/huisstijl/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
<script src="./scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Remove the dot `.` in `./styles` and  `./scripts`

Comment: First thing, it seems you are using Bootstrap 4.  If you include bootstrap.bundle there is no need to include popper.min.js    .  The order of scripts and link tags is wrong but I don't think is this the problem, however try to put script tag later. Check the paths too. Like that is hard to understand the problem

Comment: What do you see in your browser's console?

Comment: @isherwood nothing in the console, no errors

Comment: Is it possible that it's because I'm using a free web hosting?

Comment: Well, we can't help with what we can't see. Try to reproduce the problem in a snippet demo using the editor. Protip: Your link elements don't need type attributes for CSS files. That type is the default.